# How can i create link button in nextcord?

Tags: python, button, discord.py, nextcord

This is the link button i want.
[image]

this is my code:

```py
class helpcmd(nextcord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    @nextcord.ui.button(label='create thread', style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.link ,url='https://github.com/lmjaedentai/KaiCheng-Bot#commands')
    async def help(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
        #my code
```

error:

```py
  File "d:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\main.py", line 226, in helpcmd
    @nextcord.ui.button(label='create thread', style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.link ,url='https://github.com/lmjaedentai/KaiCheng-Bot#commands')
TypeError: button() got an unexpected keyword argument 'url'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because Discord doesn't return, or support a callback for URL buttons. Instead, you can do it in `def __init__` and do `self.add_item`. You can check more in the docs.

```py
class SomeView(View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() #you can do timeout here
        self.add_item(url = "some url", label = "This is a url button") #using this method doesn't have any callback.
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way for achieving the same would be with something like

```py
class MyView(ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_item(ui.Button(style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.link, url=<YOUR-URL>, label="Click Me"))
```

The initial answer by Lim is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As a full class you should do like this.

```
from nextcord.ui import View
from nextcord import Interaction,Button,ButtonStyle

class helpcmd(View):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.add_item(nextcord.ui.Button(style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.link, url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ', label="Create Thread"))
    self.value = None
    @nextcord.ui.button(label='Create a thread', style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    async def rickroll(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
      await interaction.response.send_message('got rickrolled', ephemeral=False)
      self.value = True
      self.stop()
```